# selenium IDE target currently displayed element path in dynamic web

Tags: selenium, xpath, path, ide, target

I am new in using selenium IDE and doing automation test for a dynamic website.

I have issues targeting the search button in search screen. I'm using xpath for the targets:

```
xpath=(//input[@name,'SearchCriteria') and xpath=(//button[@name,'search'])
```

This works fine for single iteration of the test but having issues when doing multiple iteration of the test. Test iteration is:
Go to search page >> set criteria >> do search >> view result details >> go to search page.

The issue is after the first iteration, the for next iteration a new instance of SearchCriteria input and search button created. However, the path still uses the first instances of the input and button. How can I ensure that the path is using the new element instance or the element that is currently displayed?

Comment: Every time you have to call driver.findElement(By.xpath(//button[@name,'search']")); , Do not make this as seperate element. You have to call this every iteration, otherwise you will get elementNotFountException.

Comment: Yes i am calling it every iteration, but the old path is still saved in HTML and that is the element return every iteration. Instead of the new and currently displayed.

Comment: Can you post your iteration code.

Comment: Im using selenium IDE 2.9.0, so here is the flow iteration code.  
Format(command - target - value)  
click - xpath=(//div[.='Item Search']) - 
type - xpath=(//input[@name,'SearchCriteria') - itemCode
click - xpath=(//button[@name,'search']) -
...
some validation checks
...


note:
1st line is for opening the iteam search screen
2nd line setting the itemCode in SearchCriteria
3rd line click search

That is one iteration (test case), for other iterations I create another test case using same code. I just use different ItemCode for search and validation check.

Answer (score 0):

As page reloaded, you need to assign elements by xpath one more time.